# Getting products from an order in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In my magento project, under My Account > My Orders (logged on customer), I am able to view the order details along with the products I ordered. Now, for each of the ordered product, I'd like to retrieve a specific attribute however, from my understanding, the code snippet at the beginning of `sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` which is `$_item = $this->getItem();` is the order itself so if I use something like `$_item->getId()`, I'm getting the order id and not the product's.

I tried researching and ended up with this code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_item->getId());
foreach($orders as $order):
    $is = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach($is as $i):
        echo $i->getProductId();
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Hoping I could use the product id to get the other attributes of the said product however, I 'm getting an error with this code with no way of telling what the error is. I've also tried something like this:

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('name', $name);

                    foreach($_productCollection as $_product):
                        $_temp = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('name_en')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                    endforeach;
```

But I keep getting 0 when I try to check the count of items in the product collection. How can I retrieve a custom attribute for the product in this page?

Comment: You can see my answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307847/product-details-in-magento/18309045#18309045

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the id of the products so I can't use it to load the details of the product.

Comment: If you are in `sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` the variable $_item is an order item, not an order so you have $item->getProductId();

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the product id now, but I'm still unable to get a custom attribute i'd like to display there.

Comment: As I said in my first comment if you look at my answer you'll see that (afteryou get the productId) you have 2 methods to get an attribute of the product. First is to do a `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);` second is to add that attribute to the system xml of the sales module from magento so that when the order item is created it will have that attribute copied to it from product

Comment: I need to display the specified attribute depending on the locale of the website (i'm using multilingual store). I used your first suggestion and it only worked on the last item on my order. For the first items, the attribute did not appear.

Answer (score 23):

This should work better:

```
   $orderIncrementId = '100000010';
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
   $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
   foreach($items as $i):
      echo $i->getProductId();
   endforeach;
```

Take a look here for more info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18629/

Answer (score 19):

While the answer given by [Electric Jesus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951773/electric-jesus) will work it contains a potential performance issue of loading products in the loop.

The correct implementation would be first to get IDs of ordered products and then load all of them at once. Assuming you already have your order loaded:

```
$orderedItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderedProductIds = [];

foreach ($orderedItems as $item) {
    $orderedProductIds[] = $item->getData('product_id');
}

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addIdFilter($orderedProductIds);
```

Comment: Magento has collection for a reason!

Comment: don't we need to call `$productCollection->load();` at the end of this

Comment: It depends on what are you going to with the collection next.

Comment: `load()` is usually called implicitly on a collection as soon as you try to do anything with it (e.g. loop through it). It's rare you ever need to call it yourself.

Comment: Ineed a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_orders = $this->getOrders();
$orderitems = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($_orders as $_order): 
  $orderitems = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();
  foreach ($orderitems as $orderitem): 
    $product = $orderitem->getProduct(); 
    echo $product->getId();
  endforeach; 
endforeach;
```

I have the same problem and this is my solution

Comment: THIS! is correct approach for load product datas from catalog.